# how to use the media request for Specific screen through Material UI library

Tags: material-ui, mui-datatable

How to use the media request `@media (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi), (min-resolution: 2dppx)` through **Material UI** library styling, for each device separately

```js
// '@media (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi), (min-resolution: 2dppx)': `url(${require('../../images/background/bg-mobile@2x.png')}), url(${require('../../images/animal/animal-mobile@2x.png')})`,

const styled = {
 animal: {
  backgroundImage: {
   mobile: `url(${require('../../images/background/bg-mobile@1x.png')}), url(${require('../../images/animal/animal-mobile@1x.png')})`,
   tablet: `url(${require('../../images/background/bg-tablet@1x.png')}), url(${require('../../images/animal/animal-tablet@1x.png')})`,
   desktop: `url(${require('../../images/background/bg-desktop@1x.png')}), url(${require('../../images/animal/animal-desktop@1x.png')})`,
  },
 },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useMediaQuery` hook to detect whether the device pixel ratio or screen resolution is high.

here you can import the images base on screen by using **makeStyle**:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  animal: {
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
    backgroundImage: `url(${require('../../images/background/bg-mobile@1x.png')}), url(${require('../../images/animal/animal-mobile@1x.png')})`,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      backgroundImage: `url(${require('../../images/background/bg-tablet@1x.png')}), url(${require('../../images/animal/animal-tablet@1x.png')})`,
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      backgroundImage: `url(${require('../../images/background/bg-desktop@1x.png')}), url(${require('../../images/animal/animal-desktop@1x.png')})`,
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.up('xl')]: {
      backgroundImage: `url(${require('../../images/background/bg-desktop@2x.png')}), url(${require('../../images/animal/animal-hd-desktop.png')})`,
    },
  },
}));
```

here, to conditionally apply styles based on the **ratio** or **screen resolution**.

```js
function Test(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const Screen = useMediaQuery(
    '(min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi), (min-resolution: 2dppx)',
  );

  return (
    <div
      className={classes.animal}
      style={{
        backgroundImage: Screen
          ? `url(${require('../../images/background/bg-mobile@2x.png')}), url(${require('../../images/animal/animal-mobile@2x.png')})`
          : " ",
      }}
    />
  );
}
```